# How to read content of HTTP Webhook callback url in azure logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I added a webhook action in logic app to call long running API(from subscribe url). I'm returning OK response and calling callback url with the result once long running process is completed. I'm struggling to read result(content of callbackurl post call) in logic app next step. Logic app shows the subscribe url response as output. How to read content of callbackurl post call in logic app?

Comment: Have you checked the body of webhook https://i.imgur.com/MjNcPFx.png

Comment: I am in a similar situation, i am trying to read the json response from the HttpTrigger Action using "body('HTTP_Webhook_Action')" but it appears to be empty/null. 

This is the error from the parseJson step: Required property 'content' expects a value but got null